# Optimize counts in SELECT with JOIN on Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, indexing, oracle10g

Hello all :) I have two tables that are about 30 millions rows each, and I'm seeking to improve performance when counts are performed.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM VEHICULE v
JOIN CLIENT c ON c.CL_ID = v.VE_CL_ID
WHERE v.VE_BRAND = 'MITSUBISHI'
  AND c.CL_COUNTRY = 'SPAIN';
```

The foreign key is declared in the VEHICULE table

```
CONSTRAINT "VEHICULE_CLIENT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("VE_CL_ID")
    REFERENCES "MY_SCHEMA"."CLIENT" ("CL_ID") ENABLE
```

And there is an index on the foreign key:

```
CREATE INDEX "MY_SCHEMA"."VEHICULE_INDEX_CLIENT" ON "MY_SCHEMA"."VEHICULE" ("CL_ID")
```

There are indexes also on the columns used for the search criteria.

The requests can take up to 40 seconds. I have looked at bitmap joins indexes but I don't know if it will help, as bitmap joins are supposed to be [for columns with low cardinalities](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/indexes.htm). Is this the only type of index for joins? I'm totally at a loss at how I can improve the performance.

EDIT:

Here is what the SQL tuning advisor of SQL developer displays (execution plan)
The sql for this query is without `AND c.CL_COUNTRY = 'SPAIN'`

```
GENERAL INFORMATION SECTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tuning Task Name   : staName9168
Tuning Task Owner  : USER
Tuning Task ID     : 12125
Scope              : COMPREHENSIVE
Time Limit(seconds): 1800
Completion Status  : COMPLETED
Started at         : 04/23/2013 15:44:35
Completed at       : 04/23/2013 15:44:36


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no recommendations to improve the statement.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXPLAIN PLANS SECTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1- Original
-----------
Plan hash value: 3808155432

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                       |     1 |    21 | 54011   (1)| 00:10:49 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                     |                       |     1 |    21 |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR                    |                       |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)              | :TQ10001              |     1 |    21 |            |          |  Q1,01 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   4 |     SORT AGGREGATE                  |                       |     1 |    21 |            |          |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                      |                       |   475K|  9745K| 54011   (1)| 00:10:49 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   6 |       BUFFER SORT                   |                       |       |       |            |          |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|   7 |        PX RECEIVE                   |                       |   475K|  6497K| 32813   (1)| 00:06:34 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   8 |         PX SEND BROADCAST           | :TQ10000              |   475K|  6497K| 32813   (1)| 00:06:34 |        | S->P | BROADCAST  |
|*  9 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| VEHICULE              |   475K|  6497K| 32813   (1)| 00:06:34 |        |      |            |
|* 10 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN          | VEHICULE_INDEX_BRAND  |   616K|       |  1621   (2)| 00:00:20 |        |      |            |
|  11 |       PX BLOCK ITERATOR             |                       |    20M|   138M| 21146   (1)| 00:04:14 |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|  12 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL            | CLIENT                |    20M|   138M| 21146   (1)| 00:04:14 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$58A6D7F6
   9 - SEL$58A6D7F6 / VEHICULE@SEL$1
  10 - SEL$58A6D7F6 / VEHICULE@SEL$1
  12 - SEL$58A6D7F6 / CLIENT@SEL$1

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - access("VE_CL_ID"="CL_ID")
   9 - filter("VE_CL_ID" IS NOT NULL)
  10 - access("VEHICULE"."VE_BRAND"='MITSUBISHI')

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - (#keys=0) COUNT()[22]
   2 - SYS_OP_MSR()[10]
   3 - (#keys=0) SYS_OP_MSR()[10]
   4 - (#keys=0) SYS_OP_MSR()[10]
   5 - (#keys=1) 
   6 - (#keys=0) "VE_CL_ID"[NUMBER,22]
   7 - "VE_CL_ID"[NUMBER,22]
   8 - (#keys=0) "VE_CL_ID"[NUMBER,22]
   9 - "VE_CL_ID"[NUMBER,22]
  10 - "VEHICULE".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  11 - "CL_ID"[NUMBER,22]
  12 - "CL_ID"[NUMBER,22]

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What does the execution plan show? Are there are indexes on `ve_brand` or `cl_country`, and if so how selective are they and which indexes is it choosing to use for each table?

Comment: you need an index on your `client` table, cf. id 12 of the explain plan.

Comment: @AlexPoole `ve_brand` and `cl_country` are indexed. I'd say they represent each 5% of the columns. The execution plans always display `INDEX RANGE SCAN` for the search criteria. (execution plan included in edit). `SELECT` queries on each table separetely are blazingly fast, but the join is downgrading performance a lot.

Comment: @collapsar The `CLIENT` table has its primary key as `CL_ID`. I was under the impression Oracle indexed automatically all primary keys. Do I need to explicitely add an index? When you say I need an index, are you refering to an index on `CL_ID`?

Comment: Can you add the execution plan for the query **with** `AND c.CL_COUNTRY = 'SPAIN'` ? Also, is this for a datawarehouse or OLTP environment? (I ask the latter question because btimap indexes are not generally suitable for OLTP environments.)

Comment: @BenoitParis oracle does, you don't, and i do - however i skipped the info that the explain plan was for a query without cl selection when reading, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create composite indexes on `client (cl_country, cl_id)` and `vehicule (ve_brand, ve_cl_id)` (both in this order).

This way you could get rid of table access on both tables.

If you have but a few countries and brands possible you could also partition the indexes by country and brand so that `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` could be used instead of `INDEX RANGE SCAN`.

You could also consider creating a cluster on `client.id` which would make the vehicle and client data to be stored in same or nearby data blocks, thus improving I/O.

Comment: I tuned the thing on our PrePROD environment (which contains less data) and the composite indexes with the primary/foreign keys do the trick :) I don't know if the performance will be great in the PROD, though. There are a few types of partitioned indexes, were you thinking of a particular one?

Comment: @BenoitParis: Unfortunately you can't list partition an Oracle global index. You would need to partition the tables by list (brand) and list (country) respectively and create local partitioned indexes.